# Does $f_n(a_n)\to f(a)$ hold?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity

Say, we have $f, f_n \in C^0(\mathbb R, \mathbb C)$ such that $f_n \xrightarrow{\text{uniform}}f$ and a sequence of reals $a_n \to a$. Does it then hold that $f_n(a_n)\to f(a)$?

I couldn't think of any counterexamples and have tried to break it into a double indexed array, then $$f_m (a_n) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty}f_m(a)\xrightarrow{m\to\infty}f(a)$$ yet it didn't work out.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you. I was motivated by the characteristic functions, in which case it's uniform. I've added it to the setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\left|f_n(a_n) - f(a)\right| \leq \left|f_n(a_n) - f(a_n)\right| + \left|f(a_n) - f(a)\right|
$$

- The first summand is smaller than $\|f_n - f\|_\infty$ hence tends to $0$.
- The second summand goes to $0$ since $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: Could it bring something if we expand like this: $$\left|f_n(a_n) - f(a)\right| \leq \left|f_n(a_n) - f_\color{red}{n}(a)\right| + \left|f_\color{red}{n}(a) - f(a)\right|$$ I mean, maybe $f_n(a_n)\to f(a)$ could then be proven under different assumptions?